# two semiprimes and a prime as three consecutive numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, semiprimes

Three consecutive numbers  comprise two semiprimes and a prime.
Examples are 21, 22, 23 and 157, 158, 159.  Do you think such
trios are endless?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the prime $p$ is the largest of the three, it is the safe prime $2q+1$ associated with a Sophie Germain prime $q$, and it is currently unknown wether infinitely many Sophie Germain primes exist.

In the remaining case, we have $p=2q-1$ instead. As far as I know, [such primes](http://oeis.org/A005382) have no established name, but are also merely *conjectured* to be infinite in number.

Comment: cunningham chain of second kind.

Comment: Can they be three consecutive numbers?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but it parses the problem, and is too long for a comment.

All primes other than $2,3$ have the form $6m\pm 1$. Since the question is about the infinite number of such trios, we need only concern ourselves with large values of $m$

In such trios, the prime number can never be the middle. If it were, one of the outside numbers would have the form $6m$ which for $m>1$ cannot be a semiprime.

Thus, the trios will be of the forms $6m-3,\ 6m-2,\ 6m-1$ or $6m+1,\ 6m+2,\ 6m+3$. In the first case, that requires $(2m-1,\ 3m-1)\in \mathbb P$ and in the second case that requires $(3m+1,\ 2m+1)\in \mathbb P$ for the trio to contain two semiprimes.

Comment: Maybe you  could find out which produces more results, of form 21, 22, 23 or of form 157, 158,159 with prime at 1st or 3rd  place in the three consecutive numbers.